# What is the best way to create SQL Azure object

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, ddl, smo

We want to create SQL Azure objects dynamically in .net 4.6 c# code running in Azure.

We could use SMO but there are no real NuGet packages.

Is there a SQL Azure SMO equivalent?

We could just inline SQL strings (!)

What is the best way to create Tables, Views etc in c# on a SQL Azure latest (v12) database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Code-First entity framework approach which would generate the MS SQL for you from the classes in your C#. Check out the following links:

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't have a C# model.